# integer fields set as null

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How to make an integer field accepts null values?

```
[Range(10, 65]
[Display(Name = "oh")]
public int oh { get; set; }
```

I'm currently using this code, but I'm getting `not null` on sql server (I haven't used [Required]).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use `?` keyword

```
public int? oh { get; set; }
```

It makes the type a `Nullable` type. Now you can set `null` to `oh`

And then check for its value by:

```
if(oh.HasValue){
  Console.WriteLine(oh.Value)
}
```

`.HasValue` says if it has value or null.

`.Value` gets you the actual value

Comment: how to affect an `int` value to `int?` then.

Answer (score 0):

use

int? for the data type.

I don't know how this will work in conjunction with Range...

Comment: how to affect an `int` value to `int?` then.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are asking. An int? is a nullable int. It can be assigned a value of null. Then you can test it oh.HasValue or oh == null to see if it has a null value. A data type of int? is equivalent to an int(null) in the DB

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nullable type:

```
int? intNullable = null;
```

With a nullable type, you have another features like a bool property called `HasValue` which return if the int has a value and `Value` to get a value without nullable.

```
if (intNullable.HasValue)
{
    int value = intNullable.Value;
}
```

In your case

```
public int? oh { get; set; }
```

The difference it the `int` is a `value type` while `int?` is a reference type. The `?` is just a shortcut to `Nullable<T>` class. Value types cannot be null, reference type can. Read more about here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use ? in cases where a value type might be null:

```
public int? oh { get; set; }
```